# Getting Post data in PHP from Android

Tags: php, android, arrays, http-post

I have created a http post request for connecting with Php server in android.
but in server side i cant extract data from the array

this is the code for making http request

```
      List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time",
        String.valueOf(location.getTime())));
 pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", new DecimalFormat("#.######").format(location.getLatitude())));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude",
            new DecimalFormat("#.######").format(location.getLongitude())));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("speed",
        String.valueOf(location.getSpeed())));

   HttpPost post = new HttpPost(endpoint);
   post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
```

In the eclipse  i loged all the values.it is printing
and i debug "pairs" it will print an array

```
      [locations[0][time]=1375788271891,
       locations[0][latitude]=12.966116, 
       locations[0][longitude]=77.638493,
       locations[0][speed]=0.0]
```

In php i tried to get this data using

```
              $lat=$_POST["latitude"];
              $long=$_POST["longitude"];
              $speed=$_POST["speed"];
              $time=$_POST["time"];
```

But iam not getting the values. whats the problem? is there aybody can help me..please reply..
Thanx in Advance :)

Comment: @Nirmal actually my problem is - the data sending from android is a array location[][]==xxxx
how to extract this data from that array. thats my problem

Comment: try to follow sanders answer. you should convert your parameters to JSON.

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($_POST) of the data your submitting and show us the results.  I don't think you can send that type of data without serializing it first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and convert your parameters to JSON and then post them to PHP.

Comment: how we can conver it into json? can u give one example?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like that, I am guessing you know how to send the data to server through php, 
Try this, in your php,

```
          $lat=$_POST['latitude'];
          $long=$_POST['longitude'];
          $speed=$_POST['speed'];
          $time=$_POST['time'];
```

Comment: i tried the same code yar..but the problem is in php it the data is getting in the format of an array.
 [locations[0][time]=1375788271891,
       locations[0][latitude]=12.966116, 
       locations[0][longitude]=77.638493,
       locations[0][speed]=0.0]

Comment: then try to get your values first in a variable, then pass it.

Comment: your right.. how we get all the post data in php ? you know? after that we can extract each values .right?

Comment: Or you can extract your data in java instead, and then pass it to php, 
Then POST data willnot be the issue.